# procedure does not exist in the target list of the run pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, procedure

I compile the package spec and body without any problem. However, when I want to test my procedure, it is not in "Target:" list of the run PL/SQL menu of the oracle sql developer. And also, I could not manage to execute the procedure from my php code.

Is there any limitations to the number of procedures or any other thing like that?

NOTE: Index: 3, Size: 3 - java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635) 
Can it be related to this?

Comment: Does your procedure perhaps have compile errors? Try `SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME = <object_name> AND TYPE = <object_type>`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

After recompiling your procedure, run the `show errors`  command. 
It displays compilation errors if you had they.

It is the most common issue reason for this.